# needed explanation about implementing the 6n-+1 algorithm for primes?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, primes

i was exploring primes algorithm in c, till i stumbled upon this one, and oh dear, the algorithm is really fast, knowing that its implementing the 6n-+1 property of prime after 2 to find the next nearest prime, but there's still some parts of the code i don't get, first why given that he starts from 2,3, and returns true if they appear respectively , what the use of the next condition `if (nb % 2 == 0 || nb % 3 == 0) return FALSE;`  ?, every other prime is not divisible by 2 and 3 other than 2 and 3 and supposedly the while do the checking so what's the use of that `if` condition ? second the while loop i was talking about is supposedly should implement 6n-+1 property but i really don't see the relativity between the math expression and the test expression in the loop? and lastly the two condition inside the while is seems to be lovely and mathematical but i don't get the use of them that much, can you clarify please. thanks a lot in advance .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int is_prime(int nb)
{
    int divisor;

    if (nb == 2 || nb == 3)
        return TRUE;
    if (nb % 2 == 0 || nb % 3 == 0)
        return FALSE;
    divisor = 6;
    while (divisor * divisor - 2 * divisor + 1 <= nb)
    {
        if (nb % (divisor - 1) == 0)
            return FALSE;
        if (nb % (divisor + 1) == 0)
            return FALSE;
        divisor += 6;
    }
    return (1);
}

int find_next_prime(int nb)
{
    while (!is_prime(++nb))
    {};
    return nb;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%i", find_next_prime(78314683));
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: That property is used to *skip* multiples of 2 and 3 as possible *divisors*, but the function still needs to know if the number passed *is* such a multiple.

Comment: @Bob_  yes indeed , could be please, say loudly why would it skip multiples of 3 and 2?

Comment: Try with pencil and paper, write all the numbers, check out all the multiples of 2 and 3, see where the remaining numbers are. Now step into the code and calculate all the values of `divisor`. I would have started from 5, then added 2, then added 4, then 2 and so on, but that's me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some theory.

First, `n % prime == (n % (prime * anything)) % prime`.

This implies that these are all correct:

```
n % prime1 == (n % (prime1 * prime2)) % prime1
n % prime2 == (n % (prime1 * prime2)) % prime2

temp = n % (prime1 * prime2)
n % prime1 == temp % prime1
n % prime2 == temp % prime2
```

Let's choose the prime numbers 2 and 3:

```
temp = n % 6
n % 2 == temp % 2
n % 3 == temp % 3
```

There are only 6 possible values for `temp`:

```
0, divisible by both 2 and 3
1, not divisible by either 2 or 3
2, divisible by 2
3, divisible by 3
4, divisible by 2
5, not divisible by either 2 or 3
```

This is the "6n-+1 property". Note that 2 is divisible by 2, and 3 is divisible by 3, so for those 2 cases we need an extra check to determine if "divisible by 2 or 3" actually means "is the prime number 2 or 3" (or if it means "can't be a prime number").

But... why stop there?

With 3 prime numbers it'd trivial to expand:

```
temp = n % (prime1 * prime2 * prime3)
n % prime1 == temp % prime1
n % prime2 == temp % prime2
n % prime3 == temp % prime3
```

Let's choose the prime numbers 2, 3 and 5:

```
temp = n % 30
n % 2 == temp % 2
n % 3 == temp % 3
n % 5 == temp % 5
```

Now there's 30 possible values for `temp`:

```
0, divisible by 2, 3 and 5
1, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
2, divisible by 2
3, divisible by 3
4, divisible by 2
5, divisible by 5
6, divisible by both 2 and 3
7, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
8, divisible by 2
9, divisible by 3
10, divisible by 2 and 5
11, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
12, divisible by both 2 and 3
13, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
14, divisible by 2
15, divisible by 3 and 5
16, divisible by 2
17, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
18, divisible by both 2 and 3
19, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
20, divisible by 2 and 5
21, divisible by 3
22, divisible by 2
23, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
24, divisible by both 2, 3 and 5
25, divisible by 5
26, divisible by 2
27, divisible by 3
28, divisible by 2
29, not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5
```

We can pack 30 possibilities into 30 bits and get the constant 0x208A2882; then use `if( (0x208A2882ULL & (1 << n%30)) != 0) /* Not divisible by 2, 3 or 5 */`.

But... why stop there?

If you chose 2, 3 and 7 you'd need 42 bits (for 42 possibilities of `n%(2*3*7)`) and could use a `uint64_t` constant; and if you chose 5 and 11 you'd need 55 bits and could use a different `uint64_t` constant; so with 2 constants you could determine "divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7 or 11".

But... why stop there?

There's no reason you couldn't choose 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 and 13; and do `temp = n % (2*3*5*7*11*13)` and have a large (30030 bit) bitfield instead a single integer constant.

But... why stop there?

For a lot of cases (your `find_next_prime(int nb)`) a single "is/isn't divisible" flag is nice, but an "offset to next integer that isn't divisible" would be a whole lot better because you could completely skip lots of numbers at once.  You'd be able to do something like:

```
int find_next_prime(int nb)
{
    do {
        if(nb > 13) {
            nb += table[nb % 30030];
            /* nb is not divisible by 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 or 13 */
```

Comment: Detail: `anything` valid when `anything >= 1`, so not quite _anything_.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code return true if the number is 2 and 3 because they are prime numbers. `if (nb % 2 == 0 || nb % 3 == 0)` is used to discard all numbers that can be divided by 2 or 3 (except 2 and 3 which have been previously accepted as prime) since they a clearly not prime numbers. This condition is mandatory to test correctly small `nb` values. Indeed, the while loop starts with `divisor` set to 6 and thus `divisor * divisor - 2 * divisor + 1 = 25` which mean `nb` must be greater or equal than 25 so that one iteration of the loop is performed. Note that 25 is chosen because all smaller numbers that are no primes can be divided by either 2 or 3, and the previous condition can catch all of them.

Regarding the main loop, the idea is that when a number is greater than 6, only numbers `nb=6k+1` and `nb=6k-1` could be (but are not necessary) prime numbers. Indeed, `nb=6k+0` can be trivially divided by 6, `nb=6k+2` can be divided by 2 as for `nb=6k+4` and `nb=6k+3` can be divided by 3. The ones that remains are `nb=6k+1` and `nb=6k+5`. The later can be rewritten as `nb=6k-1` with a different `k`.

This algorithm is a simple optimization of the one that iterates over all the possible numbers between 2 and `sqrt(nb)` to find a divisor. This optimisation is possible since one do not need to check all the divisors but only prime ones.

Answer (score 0):

`is_prime()` not functionally correct for all `int`.

Too often the focus on speed fails to provide correct functionality.

Better to get functionality right first, then worry about speed.

---

**Small value**

`is_prime()` reports `1` is prime.

Code fails to take care of small `nb`.  Simple fix:

```
// if (nb == 2 || nb == 3)
//    return TRUE;
if (nb <= 3) {
  return nb == 2 || nb == 3;
}
```

**Large value(s)**

`is_prime(primes near INT_MAX)` (e.g. 2147483647 and maybe others) are reported as *not prime*, when they are  prime.  This is due to integer overflow (*undefined behavior*) of `divisor * divisor`.

A potential fix:

```
  divisor = 6 - 1;
  while (divisor <= nb / divisor) {
    if (nb % (divisor - 1 + 1) == 0)
      return FALSE;
    if (nb % (divisor + 1 + 1) == 0)
      return FALSE;
    divisor += 6;
  }
```

Consider `div()` for the first `nb / divisor`, `nb % (divisor - 1 + 1)` calculation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really think there is a proof about this algorithm, but it's somehow unique and tricky. If you check prime numbers sequence, you will figure out that the maximum difference between two consecutive ones is 6, this is probably the idea of `divisor = 6` and `divisor += 6` . But the point is that there is no proven regulations about prime numbers sequence. So maybe it doesn't work properly on large numbers. Another cute trick he's used that couldn't be proven again, is that at least one of the 6k+1 and 6k-1 is prime. It's a nice but not too strong optimization for Sieve. Obviously, this is not the fastest prime number algorithm you can find out there, but maybe you find its' tricks useful for another problem.

Comment: exactly once tested in big numbers it fails, i've tried to and get wrong results

Comment: First I recommend you to check the data-type you're using for big numbers. It has hurt me a lot, trying a save a 1e10 or greater number in an integer. Though, as I mentioned, there's no regulation about prime numbers. If there was, you could check if a number is prime or not in O(1)!

Comment: About the proof: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html also, no, 6 isn't the maximum difference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap ;)